# How to add notes to a Gimp project?

Tags: gimp

With the latest version of Gimp (2.10.x), is there a way we can quickly type notes?  This will come very useful in instances where I am using the Measure Tool and simply need a place where I can capture my X,Y measurements, without opening another application like notepad.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could just type text on a layer.  You can then hide the text layer in the layers panel so it doesn't show, and unhide it when you want to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Image>Properties` has a "Comments" tab where you can input free text which is saved with the XCF. Keep in mind that the comment can end up in exported images (and if too big it makes the JPEG plug-in fail...).